# How to show the Id number in descending order?

Tags: php, excel

I am using PHP and I have to export the data from the database. I am using the below code which is working.

```
$sql = "SELECT `name`, `email`, `mobileno`, `data_of_added` FROM `emp` WHERE is_active=1 order by data_of_added DESC";

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();

//Get the column names.
$columnNames = array();

//Open up a file pointer
 $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
 fputcsv($fp, array('id','Name', 'Email','Mobileno', 'Date of contact'));    
 fputcsv($fp, $columnNames);

// //Then, loop through the rows and write them to the CSV file.
 $i=1;
 foreach ($rows as $row) {
 $data = array('id'=>$i++,'name' =>$row['name'],'email' =>$row['email'],'mobileno' =>$row['mobileno'],'data_of_added' =>$row['data_of_added']);
    fputcsv($fp, $data);
 }

$fileName = 'export.csv';
 
header('Content-Type: application/excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $fileName . '"');

fclose($fp);
```

I am getting all the records.

[image]

Notice that I am getting all the records in descending order and id is showing ascending `order.

This is my expected output:

[image]

How can I show the Id in descending order?

Comment: You recieve the data as you specified in your query: your query says ... `order by data_of_added DESC`. Simply change it to select id and order by `id` instead of `data_of_added` if there is an id in your table? Why do you use artificial ids?

Comment: @DefinitelynotRafal, Because there are lots of changes to delete the records and I don't want to show those records in excel.

Comment: Whats the point of having an id which says absolutely nothing? (It literally holds no value, because it is artificial, it can not reference to any row in your database). Why also just not show any id in the excel file at all? Why do you require a number in your excel file which literally has no meaning?

Comment: @DefinitelynotRafal, I have three records and if I delete the 2 then in the export it's showing 1 and 3 id but I want 1 and 2

Comment: But why? It's false then because the 2nd row has the id 3 and not id 2. I dont understand your reasoning at all. Your id just takes space **making the id completely useless**. Your id represents in my eyes something like "Row Number" in that case. Just as a note: @AlwaysSunny posted an answer to your question, which should work perfectly for what you want.

Comment: @DefinitelynotRafal, Yes, I am talking about Row number, apologize for the bad English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this way easily with the help of `count()` and decrementing the `$len` by **1**

```
 $len = count($rows);
 foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $data = array('id'=>$len--,'name' =>$row['name'],'email' =>$row['email'],'mobileno' =>$row['mobileno'],'data_of_added' =>$row['data_of_added']);
    fputcsv($fp, $data);
 }
```

**Note:** You could do that `id` order descending on your **select** query side but as you are already using `order by data_of_added DESC` so I guess above snippet will do the trick for you.

Comment: Right but I am using id as increment so I can't use the order by id.